# Google Charts "Type Mismatch" Error With Date

Tags: javascript, date, google-visualization

this is my first question!

I'm trying to make a line graph with the Google Charts API and I've run into a very strange error that I can't seem to solve.

I'm getting an error that the Date I passed to the chart is not a valid date format.

The variable that I'm passing to my Chart API looks like this:

```
rows[x] = [data[x].date, data[x].price, data[x].trendVal];
```

In this instance, the value of data[x].date looks something like this:

```
2013-01-02T00:00:00.000Z
```

The error I see in my Chrome console is:

```
Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value 2013-01-02T00:00:00.000Z does not match type date in column index 0
at gvjs_fn (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:75)
at gvjs_Iba (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:95)  ...
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `2013-01-02T00:00:00.000Z` looks like a string, not a Date object.

Answer (score 1):

try creating a date from the value...

```
rows[x] = [new Date(data[x].date), data[x].price, data[x].trendVal];
```